# How can I manipulate the full-screen button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, video

How can I manipulate the button on full-screen size so that I can change the source of the video?
The objective is to have 2 videos, a cropped one and a full size one. When the video is not in full screen (custom commands), it will show the cropped video, when it's full screen (default HTML5 commands) it will change the source to the full size video. 
The problem is that when I click this button:

[image]

The source will not change. This is the relevant code:

```
var video = document.getElementById("video1");
function fullScreen(){
     if (!document.webkitFullScreen){
        if (video.webkitRequestFullScreen) 
           video.src = "video1.mp4";
     } else {
        if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen())
           video.src = "video2.mp4";
```

So the first bit of the code works. When in full screen, the source of the video is changed. But on exiting Full Screen, the source of the video remains the same. I think it might be because I don't click the same button I used to enter full screen, so it won't go to the else statement. Anyone knows how to invoke the fullscreen function indicated in the picture and use it as my condition statement?

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is track the event that fires when the mode changes. At the moment it's not totally simple as there seem to be three browser specific events, but this code will let you track what's happening:

```
document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', tog, false);
document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', tog, false);
document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', tog, false);
document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', tog, false);

function tog(e) {
    var state = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;
    var event = state ? 'FullscreenOn' : 'FullscreenOff';

    // Now react to the event
    console.log('Event: ' + event); 

    if (event == "FullscreenOn") {
        video.src = "video1.mp4";
    } else {
        video.src = "video2.mp4";
    }
}
```